# Relative URL's not working with express-http-proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy

I have a server hosting my app plus a few microservices (all of them are very simple web apps). I would like to access these services through the internet but without opening a port for each one. so I decided that I would set up a reverse proxy ( using express-http-proxy) on the server so that I can access all the services through a single port. the problem is that while I can access the main page of each service, all the relative links point to incorrect locations.

here is an example:

service.js

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var express = require("express")
var app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.listen(8000);
```

proxy.js

```
let express = require("express");
let proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
let app = express();
app.listen(80);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello world")
});

app.use('/service/8000/', proxy("http://localhost:8000"));
```

say `index.html` contain the following line

`<a href="image.jpg">test image</a>`

if I access the microservice through the proxy none of the relative links work. and if I hover over the above link I can see where is the problem. the link looks like this

`http://myserver.com/serivce/image.jpg`

where it should like this

`http://myserver.com/service/8000/image.jpg`

notice the missing `/8000` before `image.jpg`

Comment: Try using `<base href="/8000">` in your index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I solved it. apparently, when you try to access a service that is behind a proxy you need to include `/` at the end of the URL otherwise, `node-http-proxy` will ignore the last part. example for more clarification:

if you access this URL all the relative URLs inside of it will be missing the `8000` part 
`http://myserver.com/service/8000`

while this `http://myserver.com/service/8000/` does work correctly. Notice the `/` at the end.